# Регулярное выражение нахождения суммы

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Eсть текст:

```
1)   I was 2 300 530 belarusian roubles and 2 351 dollars 12/9/2010.  
2)   After shopping 15.09.10  
3)   I was left with 1 700253 blr and 2 000$.  
4)   After shopping 16.09.10  
5)  I was left with 1 7 00  2 500 blr.  
6)   232   500blr and 10   blr.
```

Eсть регулярное выражение:

```
const string sumPattern = @"(\d+)\s*(\d*)\s*(\d*)(?=belarusian roubles|blr)|\d*\s*\d*\s*\d*\s*\d*s*\d*(?=belarusian roubles|blr)";
```

В строке 5 находит только `00 2 500`. Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Тищенко, как оно должно парсится в 5-ой строке? так?: `1 7 00  2 500`, или это же число, но пополам. IMHO там на одну цыфру больше чем должно быть

Comment: в любом случае, сейчас я вижу это так: https://regex101.com/r/Myf13C/1

Comment: должно находить число 1 7 00 2 500 . если убрать выражение (?=belarusian roubles|blr) то находит корректно, а с ним 1 и 7 отбрасывает

Comment: Во всех случаях срабатывает второе выражение после знака `|`. Благодаря `*` часть подшаблонов отбрасываются. А пятая строка не захватывается, потому что не хватает `\s*` между последней цифрой и `blr`.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот мой первый вариант (кидал до этого в коменты):
regex101.com/r/Myf13C/1
сейчас посмотрел у `Qwertiy`, теперь почти согласен с ним
RegEx который он предложил (сокращенно): `\d[\d|\s]+(?=b)`
очень хорошо работает. жаль что убрать пробел в конце придется программно
(в 6-ой строке нет пробела - это очень мешает)

Comment: Дополнил ответ. А у тебя вот тут `[\d|\s]+` фигня.

Comment: @Qwertiy без `|` нужно было писать, кажется?  
подскажи плз, что дает добавление `?\s*` в твоем ответе?

Comment: Ещё два исправления.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, так будет гораздо проще:

```
\d(\d|\s)*(?=belarusian\s+roubles?|blr)
```

или вот так:

```
\d(\d|\s)*?(?=\s*(belarusian\s+roubles?|blr))
```